# Crystal point defect - what is an oxygen defect?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals

What exactly is an oxygen defect in a semiconductor / crystal lattice structure?
Is an oxygen at a wrong place or is it missing somehow?

[image]

Comment: Pretty context dependent. Are you interested in a particular material?

Comment: For silicon: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4922251

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my pal G. Oogle, and he [said](https://newton.ex.ac.uk/research/qsystems/jones/projects/oxygen/)

> At high temperatures [oxygen] forms aggregates or clusters within the
> silicon, as well as interstitial dislocation loops. These all disrupt
> the lattice and lead to defect states in the silicon. At lower
> temperatures oxygen can still be a problem, for example through the
> formation of thermal donors which occur when silicon is annealed at
> temperatures of around 450 degrees celsius.

Comment: Read G. Oogle several times without realizing what it is :D I also googled but in another language.. the link is quite good! So, for me, this means oxygen is basically present in a way it is not wanted. Other "defects", like doping, are wanted, for example.